# After running the DO WHILE loop, scanner is not working

Tags: java

**I have no idea why my scanner for the staffID and staffPassword is not working after I choose to continue typing a new record.**

[Click to see the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrsW6.png)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String staffID, staffPassword; //Staff Record Variable
        int a = 0;
        boolean validation;
        Staff[] staff = new Staff[1000];
        int staffCount = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            staff[staffCount] = new Staff();

            System.out.print("Staff ID: ");
            staffID = input.nextLine();
            staff[staffCount].SetStaffID(staffID);


            System.out.print("Password: ");
            staffPassword = input.nextLine();
            staff[staffCount].SetPassword(staffPassword);

            System.out.println("\nEnter 1 to continue, enter 2 to stop.");
            System.out.print("Continue to add more record?(1 or 0): " );
            a = input.nextInt();


        }while(a == 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `input.next()` instead of `input.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `nextInt()` method doesn't consume the new line after hitting enter for the `a` variable. It's better to leave the `nextLine()` in its place because the `next()` works until it reach a delimiter (default white space). What does that mean? It means that if you're trying to set the `staffID` with `next()` like this : "Id For Staff", the actual `staffID` will be just "Id".

Instead of changing `nextLine()` to `next()` I suggest you to use a simple `input.nextLine()` after the last line of your `do while` (`a = input.nextInt();`)